# How to run jobs on different machines using Jenkins using Node Label parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins for a series of jobs :

Job 1 -> Job 2 -> Job 3 -> Job 4 -> Job 5.

I am using the NodeLabel Parameter plugin where I specify the linux terminal name :

```
cdfr008:linux.machine.com
```

Now Job 3 is a tricky guy which is a bat command that needs to be run on windows machine  `gdtshs.windows.machine.com`

In the configuration of the Job 3 , I checked

> "Restrict where this project can be run"

and set the Label expression under it to : `gdtshs.windows.machine.com`

However my job still fails as it picks up the parameter of Node that was passed from Job 1 i.e `cdfr008:linux.machine.com`

Restrict where this project runs options doesnt override the Node Label parameter.

Is there a solution where I could specify the nodes for Job 1,2,4,5 but ensure Job 3 is run on Windows on a  different machine ?
What plugin do I need for it ?

And if possible , could I run Job 3 (windows) and Job 4 (linux) in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Update node name into property file and inject the same in  Job3

Comment: what ? u mean not use NodeLabelParameter altogether ?

Comment: You have to use Node Label parameter, just you can put the value of server using environment variable... You can create a properties file with Key Value pair and inject the properties file in Job 3

Comment: okay. i did that. injected the windows server name from job 2 into job 3. job 3 ran successfuly but am unable to come back from job 3 to job 4 . how can i use the same Node Label parameter and and pass the linux machine name to job 4 ?

Comment: Update the properties file with new server name in Job3 and use the same property file in Job 4.